# how to make element width stay the same while text grows on hover?

Tags: html, css

Title says it all, I cannot figure out how to have an element stay the same width while the text inside it grows, if anyone knows how to do this, that would be great!
p.s, I've tried to use box-sizing, and position: relative, and all that.

```
.menu{
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #333;
}
.menu nav ul{
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu nav ul li button{
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: #d63031;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fffff7;
  border-style: none;
  border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3) !important;
  padding: 15px 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 6px;  
}
.menu nav ul li a{
  display: block;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fffff7;
  line-height: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu nav ul li a:hover{
  transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0,.8);
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using max-width?

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath yes i have :(

Comment: same width = fixed width = `width:...px`

Comment: @TemaniAfif tried, it still resizes on hover, look at the selector for hovering

Comment: What about max-width inside the :hover css?

Answer (score 0):

Just share my code, using `transform` to scale text instead of `font-size` on `a:hover`, hope it meets your requirements or gives you inspiration:

```css
a {
    display: block;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    font-size: 22px;
}

a:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.18); /* 22px * 1.18 = 26px */
    -moz-transform: scale(1.18); /* 22px * 1.18 = 26px */
    transform: scale(1.18); /* 22px * 1.18 = 26px */
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
}

li {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

li a {
    padding: 30px 20px;
    transition: all .3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">another link</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```